Efficient Server-Side Query Caching for GraphQL in Spring Boot
I'm working on a Spring Boot application with GraphQL and am looking to implement efficient server-side query caching to improve performance. I've explored some resources, but I'd appreciate insights from the community.

Recommended Approaches: What are the most recommended approaches for implementing server-side query caching with Spring Boot and GraphQL? (e.g., Caching resolvers, caching entire responses)
Caching Strategies: When choosing a caching strategy, what factors should I consider (e.g., data freshness, invalidation)?
Best Practices: Are there any best practices or common pitfalls to avoid when implementing GraphQL query caching in Spring Boot?
Existing Libraries: Are there any popular caching libraries or tools that integrate well with Spring Boot GraphQL? (e.g., Caffeine, Ehcache)
Example Code Snippet: If possible, could you share a basic code example demonstrating server-side query caching in Spring Boot GraphQL?

